# Increment through an if statment

Tags: python

```
 if pt.Z +=1    

    zHeight +=1
```

I am trying to write a code that says if a number increases then increase my new value through an if statement.

I am getting an invalid syntax because of the above statement.

What should I do?

Comment: Hi Anthony, welcome! It looks like you are missing a colon after your if statement. Other than that, what do you mean by 'if a number increases', how will the if statement know it increased? Perhaps instead you can do if pt.Z > some number then increase the other.

Comment: The code that you have provided has severe formatting and logical issues. It is very unclear where the variables are coming from and what you actually want to do with these. Either post your full code or firstly format it properly. From the snippet of code you provided, you are missing a `:` after your if statement and you are doing assignement in the if statement which is not currently supported in Python. You might want to read any of the dozens of Python tutorials and learn the langauge.

Comment: Are you trying to say "if pt.Z has increased by one since the last time I checked it"?

Answer (score 1):

The Assignment Expression operator `:=` is mentioned in [PEP 572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/), and will be included in python 3.8. Currently python is at version 3.7.2, so this feature has not yet been released.

When it has been released, your code will look like this:

```
if (pt.Z := pt.Z + 1):
    zHeight += 1
```

The current workaround would just be to do them in two separate statements:

```
pt.Z += 1
if pt.Z:
    zHeight += 1
```

Comment: I think he is really asking "whenever pt.Z increases by one, I want to also add one to zHeight".

Answer (score 0):

So, you have a class (let's say the class is called `Point`, and you have an object `pt` that is an instance of that class), and you're trying to make it so that incrementing one attribute (say, `Z`) will also make another attribute increase at the same time (say, `zHeight`).

There are ways to override the routines that run when you get an attribute and set an attribute, probably, but an easier way is to just *make a method*. Instead of

```
pt.Z += 1
```

you would implement a function in the `Point` class called `increment_Z`, which would look like this:

```
def increment_Z(self, by_how_much=1):
    self.Z += by_how_much
    self.zHeight += by_how_much
```

And then, later, you would call that function instead of accessing the attribute directly:

```
pt.increment_Z()  # to increment by 1
pt.increment_Z(3) # to increment by 3
```